# PHPExcel is not working in my case, the sheet is not downloading

Tags: php, json, href, phpexcel

I don't know what's the exact problem on my code, I have an array named `$data` that contains the following if I print it to json.

```
[{"empid":"8197","name":"Mercolita R Merleen","deduct":2625,"rembal":null,"amount":"25000","loan_id":"100047","loan_type":"Multi-Purpose Loan","duedate":"2015-12-15"},{"empid":"8359","name":"Jerome Morcilla Vergara","deduct":2152.5,"rembal":null,"amount":"12300","loan_id":"100049","loan_type":"Multi-Purpose Loan","duedate":"2015-10-15"}]
```

And put it on PHPExcel method fromArray() here is my code:

```
$worksheet->fromArray($data,null,'A6');

$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($spreadsheet);
$filename='Payday for '. $payday.'.xls';
$path="/desktop/";
    header('Content-type: application/ms-excel;');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'".xls');
    $writer->save('php://output');
    $writer->stream($path);
```

The problem is the Excel file is not downloading and after I clicked the link it redirects to the exact php file and print nothing. I just print the json just to see the exact content of my array. By the way nevermind of the mysql queries because it's working, I just can't download the Excel file.

By the way, this is my `href` code:

```
echo "<a href= '/empc/library/reports/monthlypaymentreport.php?payday=".$value."' class = 'btn btn-primary'>Generate Report</a>";
```

Never mind the echo, the $value variable comes from a loop

Comment: Check the server path to see if the Excel file is actually generated. Can you locate the Excel file? (Do ssh and change directory to output of PHPExcel)

Comment: What is `$writer->stream($path);`? `stream()` is not a method in the Excel5 Writer class, and is likely to trigger an error message that will then be embedded in the file..... are you using some kind of framework that has this method?

Answer (score 0):

There may be issue with your header information or may be space in your file name. Try to give file name with '_'(underscore). Just check out the following code:

```
function excel_demo($data){
        // Here Populate your Data in Excel Sheet
        try{
            $filename = 'your_file_name.xls';
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($CI -> excel, 'Excel5');
            $objWriter -> save('php://output');
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

By this function your file will be automatic downloaded.